# Why my error is not catched by try when fetching data from context?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

This is my private function:

```
private static func all(
    sortedBy: String?,
    ascending: Bool,
    predicate: NSPredicate?,
    limit: Int? = nil,
    deletion: Bool = false,
    context: NSManagedObjectContext
) -> [FetchableType] {
    let request = NSFetchRequest<FetchableType>(entityName: entityName)
    if let predicate = predicate {
        request.predicate = predicate
    }
    if let sortedBy = sortedBy {
        request.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: sortedBy, ascending: ascending)]
    }
    if let limit = limit {
        request.fetchLimit = limit
    }
    if deletion {
        request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = true
        request.includesPropertyValues = false
    }
    do {
        return try context.fetch(request)
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print("❌ Core Data Fetch All Error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
        return []
    }
}
```

and image representation to show the issue:

[image]

This is what I receive on console when printing parameters in line of the issue:

[image]

How do I call that functon?

```
Service.all(sortedBy: nil, ascending: true, predicate: predicate, context: NSManagedObjectContext.defaultContext())
```

Comment: That is more often than not an error because of timing, somewhere you are using asynchronous code.

Comment: I dont know if it is the reason, but yes, indeed. I have `DispatchQueue.global().async {`. Inside is `DispatchQueue.main.async {` and then inside is `tableView.reloadData()` which call `cellForRowAtIndexPath` and inside there is `Service.all(sortedBy: ...`. Does it matter?

Comment: Yes the code is jumping threads and out of sync. I would suggest discontinue the use of DispatchQueue and start converting to Concurrency/async await so you can visualize what is going on. It is no small feat but worth it. It is one or the other you can’t mix them.

Comment: You should call `fetch` inside a `perform{}` or `performAndWait{}`. And there is no error message in console?

Comment: @Larme should I call it on perform? Why?

Comment: I have found a good article about that. https://www.avanderlee.com/swift/async-await/. I am going to stydy it now. Thank you for your help.

Comment: https://www.avanderlee.com/debugging/core-data-debugging-xcode/#thread-safety  https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Concurrency.html etc.